# Passing reference outside of function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, promise

I am using https://github.com/futurepress/react-native-static-server. There are two functions, `server.start()` in order to start the server and `server.stop()` in order to stop the server. 
Starting the server from a function is done in `_startServer()`. However, how would I stop the server (`_stopServer()`)? I am not sure how to pass the reference to the server properly to `_stopServer()`.

```
export default class Foo extends Component {

    _startServer = () => {
        server.start()
            .then((localServer) => {
                this.setState({
                    serverRunning: true,
                    localServer: localServer
                })
            });
     }

     _stopServer = (refToServer) => {
          refToServer.stop();
     }

     ...

     render() {
         return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this._startServer()} />

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this._stopServer(??)} />
         )
     }
}
```

Comment: And why do you need to pass anything if you can simply use `server.stop()`?

Comment: @dfsq because I initialized `server` in `_startServer()`. When I try to access `server` in `_stopServer()`, `server` is out of scope (?) hence I cannot call `server.stop()`

Comment: Then store it as instance property.

Comment: @dfsq you mean `this.setState({server: server})`?

Comment: No, i mean instance property. `this.server = ...`.

Comment: Ah, I can access `server` in `_stopServer()` with `this.server`?

Comment: No, you can access `this.server`, not `server`.

Comment: @dfsq Not sure whether I understand correct or not. `instanceOf = server` in `_startServer()` which I then can access in `_stopServer()` through `this.instanceOf`?

Comment: this.server = server. then this.server.stop()

Comment: @dfsq thanks Would `this.setState({server: server})` work too?

Comment: Yes, it will work too.

Comment: @dfsq thanks! That referencing stuff is somewhat unclear to me - as you might realized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you assign the localServer to the Component's state with this call:

```
this.setState({
               serverRunning: true,
               localServer: localServer
           })
```

so, you can get the server with `this.state.localServer` and stop it with `this.state.localServer.stop()`

something like this:

```
_stopServer = () => {
          this.state.localServer.stop();
     }
```